# How to stop repeating the same data again and again?

Tags: c, loops, repeat

In this code, I am trying to print the remaining lines from the file except for the line which I selected with ID card number. But the data is showing me the result `like`

**Output**

```
data1....
Above are the remaining lines
data2....
Above are the remaining lines
data3....
Above are the remaining lines
```

I want the `Above are the remaining lines` to be repeated at the end once all the data is printed.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  FILE * fp1 = fopen("file.csv", "r");
  char string[200], toFind[200];
  char* lines = NULL;
  char* result = NULL; 

  printf("Enter your ID Card number: ");
  scanf("%s", toFind);

  while(fgets(string, 200, fp1)){
      lines = strtok(string, "\n");
      result = strstr(lines, toFind);

      if(!result){
         printf("%s\n", lines);
         printf("Above are the remaining lines\n");      
      }
  }    
   fclose(fp1);
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just move the second `printf` to be outside the `while` loop?

Comment: What is `lines = strtok(string, "\n");` for? Is it to remove the \n character? You have better ways to do that. Anyway you can skip that and use `string` instead of `lines` in `strstr`.

Comment: Please [edit] and add a minimal example of the `file.csv` and an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to place the string you want to print outside the `while`.

For completion you can use a `flag` to only print `"Above are the remaining lines"` if in fact there are remaining lines:

[<kbd>**`Live demo`**</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RrQO8P3sSoukc3OU)

```
int flag = 0; //flag declaration

while (fgets(string, sizeof string, fp1)) { 
    //lines = strtok(string, "\n"); //this is doing nothing meaningful
    result = strstr(string, toFind); //use string instead
    if (!result)
    {
        printf("%s\n", string);
        if (!flag)
            flag = 1;
    }
}
if (flag)
    printf("Above are the remaining lines\n");
```

Example:

File content:

```
1234....
4567....
8910....
```

Input:

```
4567
```

Output:

```
1234....
8910....
Above are the remaining lines
```